# Add ASP.NET Image from Page Method

Tags: asp.net, image, jquery

I am making an Ajax request with data to a Page Method in my code behind in my ASP.NET Web Forms application. I have a Panel control in my aspx page but I cannot get the control from that Page Method with its ID. I can get it from the `Page_Load` event though. What can I do to get the Panel control from the page method or is it not possible or maybe an alternative?

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlImages" runat="server"></asp:Panel>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetProductId() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GenerateQrCode",
            data: "{'Products':" + JSON.stringify(data) + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert(thrownError);
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('Success');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

```
[WebMethod]
public static void GenerateQrCode(List<Product> Products)
{
    foreach(var product in Products)
    {
        string qrCodeLocation = products.Where(pid=>pid.ProductId == product.ProductId).Select(s=>s.QrCode).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

        Image image = new Image();
        image.ID = product.ProductId.ToString();
        image.ImageUrl = qrCodeLocation;
        //Cannot get 'pnlImages' here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do that, `WebMethod` doesn't follow the same flow as normal page methods. It's not even a instance method but static.

You'll have to return the information on client and create the image there using javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I had that as my 2nd option. Pretty farfetched but is there anyway I can pass the JSON (my data) to server through asp.net's `Button` control and its `OnClick` event?

Comment: @user2417645: You can, but I'm not sure how that's connected to this question though.

Comment: It is not connected to the question but it is to my objective though. Would you rather I create another question? I will gladly do that also if it gets my question answered.

Comment: @user2417645: yeah, that would be the best since it's not connected to this problem, please mark this one as resolved if this asnwer helped you.